# Eloquent - Delete rows via relationship fails due to column cast type. How to force cast types?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have tables as follows:

**deliveries**

```
- id (auto increment ID)
- supplier_name (string)
- delivery_date (datetime)
- ...
```

**stock_movements**

```
- id (auto increment ID)
- entity_type (string)
- entity_id (string) //This can hold a UUID or ID.
- qty (int)
- ...
```

**Relationship**

A delivery *hasMany* stock movements with deliveries : id being linked to stock_movements : entity_id

**Problem**

Calling:

```
$delivery->stockMovements()->delete();
```

Errors:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '808498e7-a393-42f1-ab23-6ee89eb7040a' (SQL: delete from `stock_movements` where `stock_movements`.`entity_id` = 10000005 and `stock_movements`.`entity_id` is not null)
```

The raw SQL query is using the delivery ID as in integer but I think this fails as I need it to be a string, due to the cast type of the stock_movements entity_id.

**Work Around**

For now, I can get this to work by calling the delete in a loop.

```
$delivery->stockMovements()->each(function (StockMovement $sm){
     $sm->delete();
});
```

Any ideas why doing it in a loop works fine while calling delete on all records at once fails?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I have added the error message to the question, thanks.

Comment: You could try adding `protected $casts = ['id' => 'string'];` to the `Delivery` model. This should fix the issue, but might have side effects.

Comment: I was a little worried what changing the casts at model level would do, so for now I am doing: 

```$delivery->stockMovements()->each(function (StockMovement $sm){
            $sm->delete();
 });```

Which seems to work. Would this be classed as a bug that trying to do it all in one line does not work?

Comment: You mean `$delivery->stockMovements->each(`? It's not a bug: Laravel has no way of knowing that `entity_id` is a string column.